# Trouble adding new elements inside a new window executed through a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a button inside a class and that calls a define function which creates a new window, but whenever I try to put something inside the window like a Label, nothing appears. What is it am I doing wrong? What am I supposed to call when creating the Label because it seems like I'm not calling the right thing

```py
from tkinter import *

class mainTitle(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        myTitle = Label(self, text="Arithmetic & Geometric Sequence", font=("bold", 15))
        myTitle.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=50)
        
        opLabel = Label(self, text="Chooose either Arithmetic & Geometric series to calculate")
        opLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)
        
        self.ariButton = Button(self, text="Arithmetic Sequence", command=self.ariClick)
        self.ariButton.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.geoButton = Button(self, text="Geometric Sequence", command=self.geoClick)
        self.geoButton.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    def ariClick(Frame):
        ariWindow = Toplevel()
        ariWindow.geometry("300x300")
        ariWindow.title("Arithmetic Sequence")
        
        aLbl = Label(Frame, text="a") 
        aLbl.place(anchor=CENTER) #This is not appearing in the new window 
            
    def geoClick(Frame):
        geoWindow = Toplevel()
        geoWindow.geometry("300x300")
        geoWindow.title("Geometric Sequence")
        
    def qProgram(Frame):
        root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("450x350")
    mainTitle(root).grid(sticky="nsew")
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
class mainTitle(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        myTitle = Label(self, text="Arithmetic & Geometric Sequence", font=("bold", 15))
        myTitle.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=50)

        opLabel = Label(self, text="Chooose either Arithmetic & Geometric series to calculate")
        opLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)

        self.ariButton = Button(self, text="Arithmetic Sequence", command=self.ariClick)
        self.ariButton.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.geoButton = Button(self, text="Geometric Sequence", command=self.geoClick)
        self.geoButton.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    def ariClick(Frame):
        ariWindow = Toplevel()
        ariWindow.geometry("300x300")
        ariWindow.title("Arithmetic Sequence")
#i called as parent the toplevel() instance ariwindow
        aLbl = Label(ariWindow, text="aqwertyui")
        aLbl.place(anchor=CENTER)  # This is not appearing in the new window

    def geoClick(Frame):
        geoWindow = Toplevel()
        geoWindow.geometry("300x300")
        geoWindow.title("Geometric Sequence")

    def qProgram(Frame):
        root.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("450x350")
    mainTitle(root).grid(sticky="nsew")
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

vote the answer if it runs.

Comment: It still doesn't appear